# Practical solution for single bold \item in enumerate

Tags: enumerate

The output I'm looking for is this:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item Property 1
\item Property 2
\item[\textbf{3.}] Property 3
\item[4.] Property 4
\end{enumerate}
```

But I would prefer to avoid the manual counting (due to resorting, ...)
If the following would work, it would be an elegant solution:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item Property 1
\item Property 2
\textbf{\item} Property 3
\item Property 4
\end{enumerate}
```

but it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}
\item Property 1
\item Property 2
\bfseries \item \normalfont Property 3
\item Property 4
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: perfect, thank you, and I define my \bolditem

Comment: @PeptideChain You're welcome!

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to samcarter's answer is to create a clone of `\item` which adds the desired formatting:

```
\def\specialitem{%
  \@inmatherr\item
  \@ifnextchar[%]
    {\@item}%
    {\@noitemargtrue \@item
      [\textbf{\@itemlabel}]% <- The label formatting goes here
    }}
```

then use as:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Property 1
  \item Property 2
  \specialitem Property 3
  \item Property 4
\end{enumerate}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\specialitem{%
  \@inmatherr\item
  \@ifnextchar[%]
    {\@item}%
    {\@noitemargtrue \@item
      [\textbf{\@itemlabel}]%
    }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Property 1
  \item Property 2
  \specialitem Property 3
  \item Property 4
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

---

Oh, yes. It's *way* far from practical :P